# I have this as an exercise and i want to check the input numbers that are divisible by 3 and 4, is there a specific condition or what?

Tags: c

```
Write a program that will accept N even integers as input and print:
the number of numbers given as input
the average of multiples of 3
the product of multiples of 4
the product of negative numbers
The will only use the repeating while structure. Create a variant of the program that will only use the while structure.
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 int main(void) {
  int i, N, P=0, M=0, T=1, X=-1;
  printf("Enter ending value: \n");
  scanf("%d", &N);
  while (P<=N){
     if(i%2==0){  
      scanf ("%d", &i);
      P= P + 1;
      if(i%3==0){
        M = M + i;
      }
      if (i%4==0){
        T = T * i ;
      }
      if (i < 0){
        X = X * i;
      }
      M = M / 2;
     }  
 }
  printf ("The sum of the numbers is %d \n", P);
  printf ("The average of multiples of 3 is: %d \n", M);
  printf ("The product of multiples of 4 is: %d \n", T);
  printf ("The product of negative numbers is: %d \n", X);
  return 0;
```

I tried this but i dont know how to check if a number is a multiple of 4 and 3 . If it is a multiple of 3 the sum of the digits % 3 gives 0, but i dont know how to check that. For the multiples of 4 ,if the last two digits are divisible by 4. If you halve the tens and ones part of a number and the answer is even, then it is a multiple of 4 but i also dont know how to check that.

Comment: Why do you want to check the digits instead of just doing `i%3==0` and `i%4==0`? Both the tricks you describe make it easier for a human to determine whether large numbers are divisible by 3/4, but for a computer they generally aren't necessary. A simple modulus will be a fast operation on ints.

Comment: When you do `i % 3 == 0`, you're asking "does `i` have a remainder of 0 from `i / 3`" (which is analogous enough for remainder here). Divisibility by 4 (as you've done) will also work. Your lines `P = P + 1` and `M = M / 2` are slightly malformed imo: you're constantly dividing the sum by `2`, not taking the running average of all the numbers. `P` will also end up counting the amount of numbers, not their sum value.

Comment: ******while (P<=N){
     if(i%2==0){  
      scanf ("%d", &i);
      P= P + 1;
      if(i%3==0){
        M = M + i;
      }
      if (i%4==0){
        T = T * i ;

Comment: Why do you check `if(i%2==0)`? And why do you divide M by 2 (what if N is larger than 2)? There is also another issue, but that's quite difficult: if you divide an integer number by another integer number (like 8/3), then you do a so-called "integer division", which gives 2 in this case), while I believe you are looking for 2.66666. You might do `1.0*M / ...` in order to avoid this.

Comment: P = Amount of numbers that were given as input, M= avrg of numbers that are multiple of 3 ,  T = product of numbers that are multiples of 4, X=  product of negative numbers

Comment: i use if (i&2==0) so i know the number that gets in the loop is even.

Comment: Note you're checking `i%2==0` as of the _previous_ `i` value. So the first iteration will check that there's an even number of inputs, the second iteration will check that the first's was even, etc. You likely want that check after your `scanf` in the loop (it'd be a good place for a `continue;`).